# Inline Editing Weight Field on admin view

Tags: views, entities, 10

I am working on a Drupal 10 site and and I have a built an admin view that has 2 fields. Node title and Weight. I would like to be able to on that view edit the weight inline on each node and save it. It looks like the modules that could do this in previous versions of Drupal are no longer supported in Drupal 10.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?